# How to speed up server-side aggregations over partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, partitioning, query-performance

### Background

I'm generating Tukey box-and-whisker plots from a normalized, partitioned table in Postgres 10.6 on RDS with 3*10^9 rows.

I've started by using multiple views in succession consisting of an aggregation step and a subsequent outlier detection step.
First, in the aggregation step, I calculate the median, 25%, 75%, IQR, (25% - 1.5*IQR) lower whisker, and (75% + 1.5*IQR) upper whisker. Second, in the outlier detection step, I search the table for values that lie outside the whiskers.

### Aggregation

```
create view aggregation as
select
    a.a_name,
    b.b_name,
    c.c_name,
    percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by d.D) as median,
    etc for 75%, IQR, whiskers
from dtable as d
join atable as a on a.a_id = d.a_id
join etable as e on e.e_id = d.e_id
join ftable as f on f.f_id = e.f_id
join btable as b on b.b_id = f.b_id
join ctable as c on c.c_id = b.c_id
where (d.e_id between 3440500 and 3459500)
and (c.c_name = 'this_c_in_particular')
and (b.b_name in ('first_b', 'second_b', 'third_b'))
group by
a.a_name,
b.b_name,
c.c_name
;
```

Note that the `dtable` is partitioned by `e_id`

### Outlier detection

```
create view outliers as
select d.*
from dtable as d
join atable, etable, ftable, btable, ctable
join aggregation as agg on
    agg.a_name = atable.a_name,
    agg.b_name = btable.b_name,
    agg.c_name = ctable.c_name
where d.value < agg.lower_whisker or d.value > agg.upper_whisker
;
```

### Results

Currently, using a flat client-side pandas dataframe, I can perform these aggregations in under 10 seconds after the network transfer and server-side downsampling. However, on the client-side, these aggregations take at least 1 minute to run.

The (EXPLAIN ANALYZE) **plan** is available here: https://explain.depesz.com/s/0gAu

### Question

1. Is there a standard method for calculating these aggregations quickly?
2. Is there a way to get Postgres to calculate these things in parallel, 1 worker-per-group?

Any insight or discussion is more than welcome - thanks for reading.

Comment: If you want clarification if the time is spent in the database or not, run an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on the SQL query. Post the plan if you need help interpreting it.

Comment: To clarify, it's all time spent in the database, the planned rows and actual rows are close, and the default_statistics_target is set to 10000.

Comment: Ok, if you don't want informed suggestions, don't post the execution plan.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post the analyzed plan. What would you look for were you to see it?

Comment: If there are no misestimates, I would look where the time is spent and why. http://explain.depesz.com offers an execution plan anonymizer.

Comment: Thank you - I've added the anonymized execution plan above (https://explain.depesz.com/s/0gAu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution plan has some things I don't understand:

- Why is there a `Gather` node if no parallel workers were planned? From the `loops` I'd expect two workers.
- Why does expain.depesz.com not count the 895693 iterations of the bottom node (maybe it is as confused by the above as I am)?

Nonetheless, some problems can be detected right away:

- There are terrible mis-estimates (725 instead of 895693 actual rows!).
- Most of your time is spent in a sort that spills to disk.

So here is what you can improve without rewriting the query:

- Increase `work_mem` until the sort is  a `quicksort memory`.
  That should be the biggest gain.

  You don't have to increase it globally, you could run something like:

  ```
  BEGIN;
  SET LOCAL work_mem = '1GB';
  SELECT /* your query */;
  COMMIT;
  ```
- Some of the tables seem to have stale statistics. Try to `ANALYZE` all tables in question, maybe that does some good.
- You can probably scrape off a few more seconds by avoiding the ill-guided nested loop joins. Perhaps the `ANALYZE` will take care of that.

  As a last resort, you could simple disable nested loops for that query, by setting `enable_nestloop = off` for the one query with the same trick that I showed for `work_mem` above.

The scan on the partitioned table is not your problem, so you don't have to worry about parallelizing that (PostgreSQL v11 has become smarter with that).

If all of the above does not make the query fast enough, you can consider using a *materialized view*. Then you get slightly stale data, but fast.

Comment: Having implemented the suggestions in your answer, I've re-calculated the execution plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/s1BK
It appears that the statistics are still off, even though I've just run `ANALYZE`. I'll rerun with `enable_nestloop = off` and provide an updated plan.

Comment: That plan looks has already much better estimates and looks like getting rid of the nested loops won't gain you much. It is disappointing that the sort hardly got faster. I am afraid there is not much you can do about that: a median requires a sort, and sorting 937856 rows takes a while. I find it hard to believe it takes *that* long though. Maybe you can use a materialized view to speed up the query.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried a materialized view, but the reporting latency is much lower than the time it takes to refresh it. I'm effectively developing a fast materialized view at the moment, but the preliminary results aren't terribly promising, especially in light of continued scaling.

What's confounding is that, while indeed there are 1M rows to sort, they are blocked by three covariates into ~2,000 isolated groups with only ~500 rows each. Is this a case of "the planner doesn't have a crystal ball"? And do you see a way I can leverage this structure in Postgres?

Comment: I can't answer the question. I meant that the materialized view should *not* be refreshed when you run the query, but regularly in the background. The the report will operate with slightly stale data (which should be fine), but will be fast. I am not sure if it is possible to define a generic materialized view that can be used to speed up your query; probably not, now that I look at it again.

Comment: I should say: the materialized view implemented in the way you describe was an early attempt that I made, but it takes ~16hr to refresh. The plan I posted above was for a much shallower query. At this point, I'm implementing a fast materialized view following (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86779/refresh-materalized-view-incrementally-in-postgresql). If _that_ doesn't work, I'll build out a MapReduce proof-of-concept.